# ImageMosaic-JDBC Error

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver, postgresql-8.4, geotools

I'm trying to get postgis raster layers in geoserver-2.3.1, with postgresql-8.4, postgis-2.0 and gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-9.1.jar support. I'm going through the tutorial with a PNG raster that i have. In the last step i'm stuck with a java exception...can't really understand what is it!? I've tried other jdbc-postgresql driver and less tiles but the error seems to come up everytime.

Here is the output! Any interpretations? Every help is welcome. Thanks

```
java -jar ~rdfs_run/geoserver/geoserver-2.3.1/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-9.1.jar import -config ~rdfs_run/geoserver/geoserver-2.3.1/data_dir/coverages/postgis/aveiro.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix tileaveiro -tileTNPrefix tileaveiro -dir tiles -ext png
Apr 28, 2013 8:50:34 PM org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import logInfo
INFO: Truncating table : tileaveiro_0
Apr 28, 2013 8:50:34 PM org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import logInfo
INFO: Number of tiles to import: 48
Apr 28, 2013 8:50:34 PM org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import logInfo
INFO: Inserted tile AveiroRDFS_rgb_5_8.png : 1/48
...    
INFO: Inserted tile AveiroRDFS_rgb_3_8.png : 48/48
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO tileaveiro_0 (location,geom,data) VALUES  ('AveiroRDFS_rgb_5_8.png',geomfromwkb(?,4326),?) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2746)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1887)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2893)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import.sqlCommit(Import.java:1026)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import.fillSpatialTable(Import.java:856)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import.start(Import.java:401)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Toolbox.main(Toolbox.java:46)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-9.1 plugin (from Geotools) probably doesn't support PostGIS 2.0: geomfromwkb function is not defined - in newer versions it is st_geomfromwkb.

Right now i'm using an older postgis/postgres database.